# How to solve this system of equations of degree 3?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I was solving a problem and after making some substitutions I got these equations- $$a^3-2a^2+a(b^2+1)+8b-2b^2=0$$and$$b^3+(a^2-1)b+8a=0$$ I can't solve these equations. If they can't be solved, then I will post the original question. Thanks.

Comment: I think the best way so far seems to solve for a from second equation and put in the first. After that use cardano's algorithm.

Comment: Let $\lambda$ and $\mu$ respectively denote the l.h.s.s of the first and second equation. Then, $b \lambda - a \mu$ is quadratic in $a$, leading the condition $$a = \frac{1 + \sqrt{65 - 4 b^2}}{2 (b + 4)}$$. Substituting back into the second equation and solving gives five solutions: $(a, b) = (0, 0), (-1, 2), (3, -2), (1 \pm 2i, \pm 2i)$.

Comment: Nice. Could you write a complete answer. I don't know why I am getting a different quadratic.(I know you are correct, your solutions satisfy the equations).

Comment: How did you solve the big dirty equation!?!? My equation has around 8 terms...

Answer (score 0):

This is maybe a hard question but in the end it would not!

$$a^3-2a^2+a(b^2+1)+8b-2b^2=0$$

Is the same as:

$$a(a^2+b^2+1)=2(a^2+(b-4)b)$$

So you get:

$$b=\frac{-((64-4(a-2)(a^3-2a^2+a)))^{1/2}-8}{2(a-2)}$$

Or:

$$b=\frac{((64-4(a-2)(a^3-2a^2+a)))^{1/2}-8}{2(a-2)}$$

So you get a list of solutions:

$$a=-1,b=2$$
$$a=0,b=0$$
$$a=0,b=4$$
$$a=1,b=0$$
$$a=1,b=8$$
$$a=3,b=-6$$
$$a=3,b=-2$$
$$a=2,b=-\frac{1}{4}$$

Comment: I think that the roots are the ones given in Travis's comment $$\{\{a= -1,b=2\},\{a= 0,b= 0\},\{a= 1-2 i,b=-2 i\},\{a=1+2 i,b= 2
   i\},\{a=3,b=-2\}\}$$

Comment: How did you make the list of your solutions? Just from getting b in terms of a....

Comment: Yes, you've to move something out to find the solutions

Answer (score 0):

Going off of the user Travis's comment:

$$a^3 - 2a^2 +a(b^2 +1) +8b - 2b^2 = 0$$
$$b^3 + b(a^2 -1) +8a = 0$$
Multiplying the first equation by $b$ and the second by $a$ and taking the difference:

$$[ba^3 - 2ba^2 +ab(b^2 +1) +8b^2 - 2b^3] -[ab^3 + ab(a^2 -1) +8a^2] = 0$$ 
$$[ba^3 - 2ba^2 +ab(b^2 +1) +8b^2 - 2b^3] -[ba^3 + ab(b^2 -1) +8a^2] = 0$$ 
$$- 2ba^2 +8b^2 +2ab- 2b^3 -8a^2 = 0$$ 
Grouping the powers of $a$:
$$(-8 - 2b)a^2 + (2b)a + (8b^2 - 2b^3)  = 0$$ 
$$ a = \frac{-2b \pm \sqrt{4b^2 + 4(8+2b)(8b^2 - 2b^3)}}{-4(b+4)} $$
$$ a = \frac{-2b \pm 2b\sqrt{1 + 4(4+b)(4 - b)}}{-4(b+4)} $$
$$ a = b\frac{1 \mp \sqrt{65-4b^2}}{2(b+4)} $$

Note:
$$ a^2 = b^2\frac{(1 \mp \sqrt{65-4b^2})^2}{4(b+4)^2}= b^2\frac{33-2b^2 \mp \sqrt{65-4b^2} }{2(b+4)^2}$$

Plugging this back into the second equation:
$$b^3 + b(a^2 -1) +8a = 0$$
For ease of notation denote $k = \sqrt{65-4b^2}$
$$b^3 + b^3\frac{33-2b^2 \mp k }{2(b+4)^2} -b +8b\frac{1 \mp k}{2(b+4)} = 0$$

$$b^3\frac{33-2b^2 + 2(b^2+8b + 16) \mp k }{2(b+4)^2} -b +8b\frac{1 \mp k}{2(b+4)} = 0$$

$$b^3\frac{65 + 16b \mp k}{2(b+4)^2} -b +8b\frac{1 \mp k}{2(b+4)} = 0$$
If $b = 0$ then $a=0$. If $b \ne 0$ then:

$$b^2\frac{65 + 16b \mp k }{2(b+4)^2} -1 +8\frac{1 \mp k}{2(b+4)} = 0$$
If $b \ne -4$ then
$$b^2(65 + 16b \mp k) -2(b+4)^2 +8(b+4)(1 \mp k) = 0$$
$$b^2(63 + 16b \mp k) -8b \mp 8(b+4)k = 0$$
$$ \mp (b^2+8b+32) k  = b(8 - 63b - 16b^2)$$
$$ (b^2+8b+32)^2 (65-4b^2)  = b^2(16b^2 + 63b -8)^2$$
Expanding we get:
$$ -4b^6 -64b^5 - 447 b^4 - 1008 b^3 + 4224 b^2 +33280b +66560 = 256b^6 + 2016 b^5 + 3713 b^4 - 1008b^3 +64 b^2$$
Simplifying:
$$ -260b^6 -2080b^5 - 4160 b^4  + 4160 b^2 +33280 b +66560 = 0$$
Since we multiplied by $(b-4)^2$ check to see if that is a factor. After some trial and error (or some software) we obtain:
$$-260(b-2)(b+2)(b+4)^2(b^2 + 4) = 0$$
Therefore: $b = 0, 2, -2, 2i, -2i$ 
If $b=2$:
$$ a = 2\frac{1 \mp \sqrt{65-16}}{2(2+4)} =  \frac{1 \mp 7}{6} = -1, \frac{4}{3}$$
If $b=-2$:
$$ a = -2\frac{1 \mp \sqrt{65-16}}{2(-2+4)} =  -\frac{1 \mp 7}{2} = 3, -4$$
If $b=2i$:
$$ a = 2i \frac{1 \mp \sqrt{65+16}}{2(4+2i)} =  (2i+1)\frac{1 \mp 9}{10} = 1+ 2i, -\frac{4}{5} - \frac{8i}{5}$$
If $b=-2i$:
$$ a = -2i\frac{1 \mp \sqrt{65+16}}{2(4-2i)} =  (-2i+1)\frac{1 \mp 9}{10} = 1-2i, -\frac{4}{5} + \frac{8i}{5}$$

Plugging these values back in, you notice only the first values work. Therefore the solutions are (as pointed out). $(a,b)=(0,0),(-1,2),(3,-2),(1 \pm 2i, \pm 2i)$