# Logarithmic system of equations

Tags: logarithms

Solve these equations $$\log x+\frac{\log x+8\log y}{\log ^2x+\log^2y}=2$$ $$\log y+\frac{8\log x-\log y}{\log^2x+\log^2y}=0$$ Does an elegant solution exist? If not, how do I solve two cubic equations. See here [How to solve this system of equations of degree 3?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1249467/how-to-solve-this-system-of-equations-of-degree-3)

Comment: The logs just complicate stuff. Take $X= \log x$ and $Y = \log y$ to get a much simpler looking system. Try to multiply the first equation by $X$ and the second by $Y$ and subtract the two equations.

Comment: That is what someone said on the previous question(see link). After that I get b in terms of a, it will he quite tedious to substitute back...

Answer (score 1):

Let $\log x = u$ and $\log y = v$.  Your system becomes

$$ \eqalign{u + \dfrac{u+8v}{u^2+v^2} &= 2\cr
            v + \dfrac{8u-v}{u^2+v^2} &= 0\cr}$$
Put the $2$ on the left side, and multiply by $u^2+v^2$:
$$ \eqalign{{u}^{3}+u{v}^{2}-2\,{u}^{2}-2\,{v}^{2}+u+8\,v &= 0\cr
{u}^{2}v+{v}^{3}+8\,u-v &= 0\cr}$$
The resultant of the two left sides with respect to $v$ is 
$$260\,u \left( u-3 \right)  \left( u+1 \right)  \left( {u}^{2}-2\,u+5
 \right) 
$$
which must be $0$ for a solution.  With $u=0$ we get $v=0$ (not a solution to the original system).
With $u=3$ we get $v=-2$.  With $u=-1$ we get $v=2$.  With $u = 1 \pm 2 i$ 
(the roots of $u^2 - 2 u + 5$) we get $v = \pm 2 i$.

Comment: OK, but how did you eliminate v?

Comment: Using Maple.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resultant